# IIS in Classic Mode ignores Sitecore, does not loads the startItem

Tags: iis, sitecore, application-pool

I am using Sitecore 8.1, and our IIS crashes quite often in production - on average, 2 times a day.

Following [this guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/scrapbook/64%20bit%20environments.aspx) to improve Sitecore stability on 64-bit machines I have set the **Enable 32-bit Applications** option to **True** and changed the application pool's **Managed Pipeline Mode** to **Classic**.

Sitecore now displays the empty "Default Page" page, and even after deleting its file it attempts to simply list the directory content rather than loading my Sitecore application as it always did in Integrated mode.

Does anyone knows how can I configure IIS in order to have Sitecore to work properly in Classic Mode?

Comment: The article you post is from 2008.  Why you need Classic mode?

Comment: What version of Sitecore you want to install ?

Comment: Hi Sitecore Climber,

We recently are having a string of hard server crashes that we cannot troubleshoot. Every time the same Windows DLL are mentioned in the Event Manager and we could not find a solution to it. Browsing around for workarounds, I found that article and decided to give it a shot. I am using Sitecore 8.1.

Comment: Which DLL is causing you issues?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll

C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll

Also, I receive the following message: Unable to open the Server service performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a solution to switch your Application Pool to Classic mode to stable your solution.

In Sitecore 8.1 : Classic mode for IIS has been deprecated, and the httpModules and httpHandlers elements have been removed from the Web.config file.

Informations about classic mode deprecated you can find [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes)

It's very difficult to find exactly your problem, I suggest you to open a support ticket.

Comment: Thank you. I will give up using Classic Mode as an attempt to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do it catch the actual crash of the IIS app pool with DebugDiag. You install it and then configure it to watch your app pool until it crashes. Once it does, DebugDuag will dump the memory of the app pool to your hard drive. You can finally analyze that for the exact function and cause of the dump. You most likely have a process that is spinning off into a stack overflow in unmanaged code.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/